# haproxy ssl password protected private key

Tags: ssl, haproxy, password, private-key

Usage: Haproxy as SSL termination

Requirement: Our private keys are password protected and we are not allowed to remove the password for the private key

Problem:
If i run the following command `haproxy -f /pathtoconf` a password prompt is shown and once the password is provided haproxy starts up

To overcome this issues i have used expect script which automatically provides the password

**Script to auto populate the password**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout 20
spawn nohup haproxy -f /opt/reverse-proxies/demo.cfg
expect "Enter PEM pass phrase:"
send "password\r"


expect_background
expect eof
exit
```

I am planning to automate it using ansible-playbook but  my question is there any clean way to provide the password for private key, i did some search on this but  couldn't find any configuration for the same. There were some statements from haproxy team that there is plan to provide a clean approach but couldn't make it in 1.6 and planning to do that in 1.7. I looked into release notes of 1.7 but couldn't find much on that topic. Is there any configuration which haproxy provides for private key password Or if any one has implemented a nice solution to overcome this problem could you please guide me in that direction.

**My sample configuration**

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1 local2 debug

defaults
  timeout connect 5000
  timeout client  50000
  timeout server  50000

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# main frontend which proxys to the backends
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
frontend  main
    log global
    bind *:4000 ssl crt /tmp/server.2.crt.pem
    default_backend             app


#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# round robin balancing between the various backends
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
backend app
    log global
    mode http
    server  app1 127.0.0.1:4002
```

Answer (score 0):

> we are not allowed to remove the password for the private key...expect script which automatically provides the password

Either you are breaking the intention of the security policy or your security policies are maintained by cut & paste monkeys who don't actually understand IT security.

On the *assumption* that there is a requirement to protect the key then there's some choice in how you implement this. Obvious solutions are...

- put the cleartext on a different host and restrict access via IP address / MAC address / client cert (although the latter creates a chicken and egg scenario)
- (assuming this is on Linux) Use the [virtual HSM capability](https://linux.die.net/man/1/keyctl) in the kernel to store the key. You still need to populate the data at boot time - but not every time you restart haproxy